# How do I create a group for the workflow?

Tags: workflow

When starting the workflow process I want to be able to just type in a group name and have the email notification sent to everyone in that group rather than having to type out every individuals name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharePoint permissions group, add everyone to it, and use the group name in the "To" of your email.

Comment: An AD group or distribution list can also be used.